# Is there a way to combine verifyNoInteractions with timeout

Tags: java, mockito

I have a piece of java code that runs in a CompletableFuture#runAsync block and I want to verify that in this block, a specific service is never called.

Normally to verify that it is actually called, I can use the `timeout` VerificationMode to assert when the runAsync is likely completed

```
verify(myService, timeout(500)).methodX(param);
```

But in my case I want to check if the service had no interactions. Normally this is done with `verifyNoInteractions(myService);` but this fires immediately and has a high chance for false positives.

The workaround is that, for every method in the service, I type use the `times(0)` VerificationMode e.g.

```
verify(myService, timeout(500).times(0)).methodX(param);
verify(myService, timeout(500).times(0)).methodY(param);
verify(myService, timeout(500).times(0)).methodZ(param);
```

But this is an awful idea for all obvious reasons.

I know another possibility would be adding `Thread.sleep(500);`, but I want to use the Mockito API if possible. I just have not seen it done elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful, what you are doing using `times(0)` does not work as you expect.
Indeed, one can try this piece of code to notice that the timeout is not actually reached, and as soon as the first valid Mockito evaluation passes, the `verify` assertions passes.

```java
  private static class TestAsync {
    void test() {
      System.out.println("test");
    }
  }

  @Test
  void testAsyncWaitZeroTimes() {

    var testAsync = Mockito.mock(TestAsync.class);
    doCallRealMethod().when(testAsync).test();

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        testAsync.test();
      }
    }, 1000);

    verify(testAsync, timeout(2000).times(0)).test();

  }

  @Test
  void testAsyncWaitOnce() {

    var testAsync = Mockito.mock(TestAsync.class);
    doCallRealMethod().when(testAsync).test();

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        testAsync.test();
      }
    }, 1000);

    verify(testAsync, timeout(2000).times(1)).test();

  }

  @Test
  void testAsyncWaitReachingTimeout() {

    var testAsync = Mockito.mock(TestAsync.class);
    doCallRealMethod().when(testAsync).test();

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        testAsync.test();
      }
    }, 2000);

    verify(testAsync, timeout(1000).times(1)).test();

  }
```

You will notice that the `test` is printed only in the `testAsyncWaitOnce` test.

What I am doing is using a third-party library called [`awaitility`](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility), and allow to do something like:

```java
  @Test
  void testAsyncWaitUsingAwaitilityShouldNotBeCalled() {

    var testAsync = Mockito.mock(TestAsync.class);
    doCallRealMethod().when(testAsync).test();

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        testAsync.test();
      }
    }, 5000);

    await().during(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .until(() -> Try.run(() -> verify(testAsync, never()).test())
                           .isSuccess());

  }

  @Test
  void testAsyncWaitUsingAwaitilityShouldBeCalledOnce() {

    var testAsync = Mockito.mock(TestAsync.class);
    doCallRealMethod().when(testAsync).test();

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        testAsync.test();
      }
    }, 1000);

    await().timeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .until(() -> Try.run(() -> verify(testAsync, times(1)).test())
                           .isSuccess());

  }
```

This way we can see the time is correctly awaited and no interactions have happened in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Combine Timeout with How often it should appear

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.timeout;

...

verify(spy, timeout(5000).times(1)).doWhatever(comparedArgument);
```

Wait for `5000` milliseconds to execute `doWhatever` exactly `1` times and check that the argument equals `comparedArgument`